# Grammar mistakes in a PhD application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, statement-of-purpose

I just submitted my SoPs for PhD programs in Earth Science and I realized I wrote "for these reason" instead of "for this reason". I also wrote "this inquiries" instead of "these inquiries". Now, I am worried that I'm not going to get into any grad school. I am an international student, valedictorian and I gained great research experience in my country and the US. Do you think these mistakes are going to hurt my application?

Comment: No. Your application as a whole is not the summation of two grammatical errors.

Answer (score 9):

There is certainly no way that these mistakes alone will hurt your application.  If the admissions committee is concerned about your English fluency, there are other things they can look at: your GRE and/or TOEFL scores and your personal statement / statement of purpose.  If you are doing okay on those, then you have nothing to worry about.

Even if your verbal / writing / English skills do look somewhat shaky, that still should not get your application for a PhD in earth sciences automatically tossed out.  The committee would want to weigh your weaknesses there against your strengths in other areas.  What would be a problem is if your writing skills were so poor that they just couldn't understand you at all.  Based on the five line writing sample given by your question: this is absolutely not going to be the case.

In summary: don't worry, you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

The only case I can imagine these two mistakes seriously hurt you is when **(1)** you apply in linguistics, philosophy and related fields (where natural languages are what counts a lot) or when **(2)** you are evaluated completely equal with another candidate and someone in the committee is nit-picking on grammar mistakes.

Other than that, we all do make mistakes, and these two ones are so minor that they shall be ignored.